# Using noindex nofollow to Fix mobile usability warning from Google

Tags: mobile, seo

I have a mobile website that does show as being mobile friendly using the [Google Mobile Test Tool](https://www.google.co.uk/webmasters/tools/mobile-friendly/) But I got a message saying that there were usability errors on a calendar page that is part of the website but  not  mobile friendly.  I will eventually make this page mobile friendly but for now I just want Google **not** to see it as part of the mobile website.  So my question is by using noidex nofollow on that page will Google ignore it and not rate it for usability.

Comment: If you blocked by robots.txt then google wouldnt be able to tell if mobile friendly or not. Dont know how that transpires for overall usability.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, noindex nofollow will make the Google crawlers to ignore the website page however before you build your robots.txt, you should know the risks of this URL blocking method. Robots.txt instructions are directives only,robots.txt files cannot enforce crawler behaviour to your site; instead, these instructions act as directives to the crawlers accessing your site. While Googlebot and other respectable web crawlers obey the instructions in a robots.txt file, other crawlers might not. Therefore, if you want to keep information secure from web crawlers, it’s better to use other blocking methods, such as password-protecting private files on your server.

Comment: Bit confusing here, you start of with noindex, nofollow and then change to robots.txt ? These are different things.